# Heapsort function behaves the same with push and unshift.(Perl)

Tags: perl, sorting

I've been trying to implement a heap-sort function but it sorts the array in reverse order. The weird part is that it doesn't matter if I use unshift or push, the elements always get printed reversed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.014;
no warnings 'recursion';

sub heapify{
  my $index = pop @_;
  my $larger;
  unless ($index > int(@_/2-1))
  {
    my $left  = 2 * $index + 1;
    my $right = 2 * $index + 2;
    if($right < @_ && ($_[$left]<$_[$right]))
    {
      $larger = $right;
    } else {
      $larger = $left;
    }
    if($_[$index] < $_[$larger])
    {
      ($_[$index],$_[$larger]) = 
      ($_[$larger],$_[$index]) ;
      heapify(@_,$larger);
    }
  }

}

sub max_heap{ 
  for(my $i = int(@_/2 -1) ; $i > -1; --$i){
    heapify(@_,$i);
  }

}

sub heapsort{
  return unless @_ > 1 ;
  max_heap(@_);
  my $last = shift(@_);
  heapsort(@_);
  push(@_,$last);
}


my @test = (9,3,13,7,6,78,2);

heapsort(@test);

say "Heapsorted:";
say join("\n",@test);
```

Comment: If you care about speed, why not let perl do the sorting?

Comment: I don't really care about the speed. I just want to learn how to implement the algorithm correctly and it seems I have done something wrong since it takes 30-40 seconds to sort a 1000-element array.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, this code is very fast for me: But that is because it doesn't even compile. Would you mind fixing your errors to the best of your ability? (E.g. `for` needs a block, not just a statement)

Comment: My mistake, it was a last-minute change and I forgot to fix it. Can you reproduce now?

Comment: I would try to pass array reference around, ie. `heapify($aref,$i);` instead of array, plus array assignment `@_ = heapify(@_,$i);`

Comment: That's weird, it compiles without warnings for me and the result is perfect if not for the execution speed.

Comment: Silly me. I was running it with constants like `heapsort(1, 2, 3)` – which doesn't work as you sort in-place

Comment: It's probably something among those lines. I'll experiment a bit.

Comment: Have you looked into http://search.cpan.org/~atoomic/Sort-XS-0.10/lib/Sort/XS.pm ?

Comment: Like I said this serves educational purposes so a cpan module won't help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Pseudocode)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = reverse 1..500;
heapSort(\@a);
print "@a\n";

sub heapSort {
    my ($a) = @_;
    # input:  an unordered array a of length count

    # (first place a in max-heap order)
    heapify($a);

    my $end = $#$a; # //in languages with zero-based arrays the children are 2*i+1 and 2*i+2
    while ($end) {
        # (swap the root(maximum value) of the heap with the last element of the heap)
        @$a[$end, 0] = @$a[0, $end]; # swap(a[end], a[0])
        # (decrease the size of the heap by one so that the previous max value will
        # stay in its proper placement) 
        $end--;
        # (put the heap back in max-heap order)
        siftDown($a, 0, $end);
    }
}
sub heapify {
    my ($a) = @_;
    my $count = @$a;
    # (start is assigned the index in a of the last parent node)
    my $start = ($count - 2 ) / 2;

    while ($start >= 0) {
        #(sift down the node at index start to the proper place such that all nodes below
        # the start index are in heap order)
        siftDown($a, $start, $count-1);
        $start--;
        #(after sifting down the root all nodes/elements are in heap order)
    }
}
sub siftDown {
     my ($a, $start, $end) = @_;
     # input:  end represents the limit of how far down the heap
     #              to sift.
     my $root = $start;

     while ($root * 2 + 1 <= $end) { # (While the root has at least one child)
        my $child = $root * 2 + 1; # (root*2 + 1 points to the left child)
        my $swap = $root;          # (keeps track of child to swap with)
        #(check if root is smaller than left child)
        $swap = $child if $a->[$swap] < $a->[$child];

        #(check if right child exists, and if it's bigger than what we're currently swapping with)
        $swap = $child + 1 if $child+1 <= $end and $a->[$swap] < $a->[$child+1];

        # (check if we need to swap at all)
        if ($swap != $root) {
            # swap(a[root], a[swap])
            @$a[$root, $swap] = @$a[$swap, $root];
            $root = $swap; # (repeat to continue sifting down the child now)
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the algorithm from the wikipedia?

Comment: @Veritas yes, you have link above. It uses array reference and is much faster.

Comment: Yea but it sorts everything in reverse order. And the weird part is that it does the same with both unshift and push.

Comment: `@_ = reverse @_;` as last line in `heapsort()`

Comment: Well obviously that's a fix but I would prefer knowing what causes this. How this works is that it creates a heap, removes the first element repeating(recursively) for the rest of the heap and then pushes the removed element to the end. At least that's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is to mention the required change in the code by Сухой27 answered Dec 31 '13 at 17:46.

Code works fine when input array has even n number of elements, but goes wrong when n is odd.

For an input like  `@a = qw(10  11  2);`

Output would be `= 2  11  10`

The output is wrong because in the first step, the above script skips checking of left child of last parent. When left is larger, the same does not swap with its parent.

The fix is simple:

```
 my $start = int(($count - 2 ) / 2);
```